# Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentChangeAction<unknown>[]>'. Question

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

I've come across some error and I am having trouble figuring out what might be the problem. It seems to be related to Typescript and types, but I am not able to fix it by installing the relevant package.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { Exercise } from './exercise.model';

u/Injectable()
export class TrainingService {
  exerciseChanged = new Subject<Exercise>();
  exercisesChanged = new Subject<Exercise[]>();
  finishedExercisesChanged = new Subject<Exercise[]>();
  private availableExercises: Exercise[] = [];
  private runningExercise: Exercise;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {}

  fetchAvailableExercises() {
    this.db
      .collection('availableExercises')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map(docArray => {
        return docArray.map(doc => {
          return {
            id: doc.payload.doc.id,
            name: doc.payload.doc.data().name,
            duration: doc.payload.doc.data().duration,
            calories: doc.payload.doc.data().calories
          };
        });
      })
      .subscribe((exercises: Exercise[]) => {
        this.availableExercises = exercises;
        this.exercisesChanged.next([...this.availableExercises]);
      });
  }
}
```

I tried adding:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
```

I also tried installing:

```
npm install u/types/rx --save
```

I am thinking I might have to add something in the module section or something, does someone have a clue?

Comment: Does this constitute a [mcve] that someone can drop into their own IDE to demonstrate the issue for themselves?  Or can you provide a link to a web IDE that shows this happening?

Comment: You should wrap map() inside .pipe()

Comment: depending on your rxjs version you need to improt map operator: import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; and (like Rexhin mentioned) add pipe: .snapshotChanges().pipe(map(docArray..)) l

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RXJS 6 or above you have to use

```
.pipe(map(() => {your code}))
```

you can review how they write the operators here
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators